# ready to use uint route constraint?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-routing

I have a .NET Core Web API project and my Ids are integers starting at 1. In most samples I see something like this

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUserByIdAsync([FromRoute] int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Since I know Ids must be greater than 0 I also added the `:min(1)` route constraint. But wouldn't it be better to change the integer datatype to `uint`? The route would then be

```
"{id:uint:min(1)}"
```

and the method parameter will change to

```
[FromRoute] uint id
```

but unfortunately the uint constraint does not exist. I think when not using GUIDs for Ids this is a standard problem because databases will autogenerate integer Ids starting at 1. I tried to create my own route constraint:

In the `Startup` file I added this to the `ConfigureServices` method after `services.AddControllers()`

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(routeOptions =>   
{  
    routeOptions.ConstraintMap.Add("uint", typeof(UIntRouteConstraint));  
});
```

and the route constraint itself is pretty straight forward

```
public class UIntRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

        if (route == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(route));

        if (routeKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(routeKey));

        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

        if (values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out object routeValue))
        {
            // check if param is a uint
            return UInt32.TryParse(routeValue.ToString(), out uint number);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This seems to work as expected when testing it by calling the get user by id url. But I'm not sure if this constraint is bullet proof and if I need those null checks before.

Does a ready to use `uint` route constraint exist? I think I'm not the only one needing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does a ready to use uint route constraint exist?

No.

Based on the currently available documentation.

> The ASP.NET Core [Constraints](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Http/Routing/src/Constraints) folder provides good examples of creating a constraints

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core: Custom route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-route-constraints)

If you review the built in constraints you will see that they follow similar formats and checks for null.

After reviewing [`IntRouteConstraint`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Routing/src/Constraints/IntRouteConstraint.cs), for example, I noticed some checks that were not in your example.

It is possible that

```
values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out object routeValue)
```

can result in `routeValue` being *null*.

As for the additional null checks, one ideally only needs to check the parameters one intends to use within the scope of the current function.

Refactored code:

```
public class UIntRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, 
        RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {

        if (routeKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(routeKey));

        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

        if (values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out object routeValue) && routeValue != null) {
            if (routeValue is uint)
                return true;

            string valueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return UInt32.TryParse(valueString, out uint _);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good :) The project doesn't use GUIDs for IDs so I think this is a good approach. Maybe others can use it too

Comment: @Question3r I personally believe this constraint does not exist because the same can be achieved using combinations of existing constraints

Comment: you mean using the `int` constraint and a range constraint going from 1 to int.max?

Comment: @Question3r yeah. something like that.